# Turn select * into individual field names in DBeaver

Tags: sql, select, dbeaver

I stumbled upon one of the most amazing features in DBeaver, where I had:

```
select *
from foo
```

And I hit some key combination that turned `*` into an individual list of field names:

```
select field1, field2, field3, field4
from foo
```

The problem is I cannot repeat it, no matter what I try, and I can't find any documentation on the feature.

If anyone knows the key combination to make this work, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe `CTRL + SPACE`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lukasz is right.
After you type the *asterisk* `*`, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and the *intellisense* window (SQL Assist) will appear with the field names from the table.

Comment: DBeaver 6.3.4 includes the alias now when it explodes field names!

Comment: @Hambone I can't replicate this. It only gives me assistance/autocomplete for the first table, unaliased and ignoring the joined tables. I'm on version 22.2.1

Comment: @gcr -- just a thought, but did you try it before running your first query?  I wonder if it hasn't connected to the database and downloaded metadata yet

Comment: @Hambone No I tried it afterwards